# SQL Server Express connection string on server not working

Tags: c#, jquery, connection-string, sql-server-express

I have uploaded my project to a server and everything works fine until I try to "log-in" or "register" using EF

Interestingly, on my PC, I have got this to work with SQL Server Express & SQL Server Compact - it just does not work on the server

On the server, I have SQL Server Express installed

Here is the connection string

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"
     connectionString="data source=(localhost);Integrated Security=SSPI;
                       database=aspnet-MvcDealerConn-20121005200308;
                       AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnet-MvcDealerConn-20121005200308.mdf;
                       User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: I can't see the error - the app just hangs and then after about 15 seconds says "error loading page" - This is crazy - it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Is that UserInstance/User Instance?

Comment: 1) User instances are deprecated, 2) Should it not be `Data Source=(localhost)\SQLEXPRESS` if you *just had SQL Express installed*; the default named instance name for SQL Express is ... `SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 0):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! And it's deprecated, too - don't use it!

The way I would solve this is:

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `DealerConn`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=servername\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DealerConn;User ID=SomeUser;Pwd=SecretPwd
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Since it's hosted on a remote server, I also believe you need to most likely provide a separate, explicit User name and password (and you cannot use the `Integrated Security=SSPI;` tag)

Comment: OK - this is what I tried...following what Marc_s said to do...                                                                     <add name="DefaultConnection"
                                                                           connectionString="wsp27xxxxxxx.xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;
                       database=DealerConn;
                     User ID=xxxxxx;Pwd=xxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />